# Error permission 13 when convert an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I try to convert all images from my directory in webp using a python script but when I try to use function I get this error: Permission error 13

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL
import os
import glob

files = os.listdir()

images = [file for file in files if file.endswith(('jpg', 'png', 'jfif', 'jpeg'))]

print(f"Images {images}")

images = [file for file in files if file.endswith(('jpg', 'png', 'jfif'))]

class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for other exceptions"""
    pass

def convert_image(image_path, image_type):

    im = Image.open(image_path)
    im = im.convert('RGB')
    image_name = image_path.split('.')[0]
    print(f"This is the image name: {image_name}")

    if image_type == 'jpg' or image_type == 'png' or image_type == 'jfif':
        im.save(f"{image_name}.webp", 'webp')
    else:
        raise Error

    for image in images:
        if image.endswith('jpg'):
            convert_image(image, image_type='jpg')
        elif image.endswith('png'):
            convert_image(image, image_type='png')
        elif image.endswith('jfif'):
            convert_image(image, image_type='jfif')    
        else:
            raise Error

convert_image('C:\\Users\\Dani\\Desktop\\Webp', 'png')
```

This is my script and directory

And this is the errors
Which I get when I run the script
How can I get rid of these permissions or what should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZosM.png)

```
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\Dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Dani\Desktop\Webp\converter.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\Dani\Desktop\Webp\converter.py", line 26, in convert_image
    image_name = image_path.split('.')[0]
  File "C:\Users\Dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2904, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Dani\\Desktop\\Webp'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Show *the full stack trace and error message* in your question, not just a redacted version of the message.

Comment: Done @Barmar i put all errors

Comment: "Permission denied" should be a clear enough error message.

Comment: `Webp` is a directory, you're trying to open it with `Image.open(image_path)`. What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: That traceback can't be right. The error is happening inside `Image.open()`, not on the line `image_path.split('.')[0]`

Comment: Yes webp is the directory

Comment: So why are you trying to open it as an image file?

Comment: Yes, all images from webp folder with png extension

Comment: You should loop through all the files in the folder, not try to open the folder itself.

Comment: How can I do this? I tried to write this function to be more clean

Comment: This code is very confusing. Instead of looping through the files in the Webp folder, you're looping through the files in the `images` list.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether the filename is a file or a directory. If it's a directory, loop through the files in the directory and call the function recursively. If it's a file, convert it.

```
def convert_image(image_path, image_type):

    if image_type not in ('jpg', 'png', 'jfif'):
        raise Error

    if os.path.isdir(image_path):
        for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(image_path, '*.'+image_type)):
            convert_image(file, image_type)
        return
    
    im = Image.open(image_path)
    im = im.convert('RGB')
    image_name = image_path.split('.')[0]
    print(f"This is the image name: {image_name}")

    im.save(f"{image_name}.webp", 'webp')
```